# Getting .htaccess file to work in subfolders

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess

I finally figured out how to get certain things to work on my website using the .htaccess file.

1. Redirect all non-www requests to www version. DONE.
2. Remove all php file extensions and add a trailing slash. DONE.
3. Prohibit directory views. DONE.
4. Limit caching. DONE.
5. Redirect 404 requests to home page. DONE.

This all seems to work well, but only in the ROOT directory.

It doesn't work well in subfolders. PHP extensions aren't removed. Folder paths in URLs disappear.

As I'm new to .htaccess files and regular expressions, and getting to this point took some time and lots of trial and error, I'm hesitant to tamper with the code any further.

I would appreciate any guidance on:

1. How to optimize this file for subfolders.
2. How to optimize this file in general.

Thank you.

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect non-www requests to www version
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.net/$1 [R=301,L]

# remove .php file extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

# disable directory view on web pages
Options -Indexes

# cached pages will expire in 5 days
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"

# re-direct 404 pages to home page
ErrorDocument 404 /
```

Comment: Are there any existing .htaccess files in the subdirectories? These will always take precedence over the .htaccess in the root folder.

Comment: No. Only .htaccess file is the one in root directory.

Comment: You do not remove the .php extensions, You just add if missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keep your `DocumentRoot/.htaccess` like this:

```
# disable directory view on web pages
Options -Indexes

# cached pages will expire in 5 days
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 days"

# re-direct 404 pages to home page
ErrorDocument 404 /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# redirect non-www requests to www (both http and https)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L,NE]

# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,5}|/)$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]

## hide .php extension
# To externally redirect /dir/file.php to /dir/file
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.*?/)?(?:index)?(.*?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]

# To internally forward /dir/file to /dir/file.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Once you verify it is working fine, replace `R=302` to `R=301`. Avoid using `R=301` (Permanent Redirect) while testing your mod_rewrite rules.

Comment: Thanks for my loop problem old answer. The loop is my problem :-) Here you can add one `/` in `RewriteRule ^ /%1%2/ [R=302,L,NE]` because he ask for trailing slash or that will be a redirect loop ;-)

Comment: Everything is testing well. Thank you.

Comment: Replacing my code for "# redirect non-www requests to www version" with your enhanced version is a big plus. Not only is yours cleaner and more concise, but now I can copy this code to my other sites without have to manually edit the host name each time.

Comment: Yes that's what the thought was behind the change. It combines http and https in same rule also. Just change 302 to 301 once you have tested and verified all the rules.