# .htaccess - Remove www, force https, remove php and remove trailing slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to archieve the following with least amount of redirects;

- Remove WWW
- Force HTTPS
- Remove php extension
- Remove end trailing slash

What i have so far and is working:

```
RewriteEngine On

# REMOVE WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# REMOVE TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# REMOVE PHP EXTENSION
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Current behaviour:

```
http://www.example.com/functions.php -> https://example.com/functions
```

(works with 4 redirects)

OR

```
http://www.example.com/functions/ -> https://example.com/functions
```

(works with 4 redirects)

Does anyone have any suggestions how to make this work with fewest possible redirects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting .htaccess file to work in subfolders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27642401/getting-htaccess-file-to-work-in-subfolders)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't hurt to just always rewrite to https and lose the www in one step. Trailing slash is unchanged, but lost a line on removing php-extenstion by inverting the Cond.

```
# REMOVE WWW & FORCE HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# REMOVE TRAILING SLASH
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301] 

# REMOVE PHP EXTENSION if there's no file with this name
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
```

If you also need handling for files that were requested as `file/` without `.php`, you should stay with your code for the final part:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

Comment: First part with combining the removeral of www and force https works. Last part with removing extionsion does not work though. But still better now i only have 3 redirects.

Comment: You want to remove `.php` when the requested file does not actually exist, right? You had two rules for that, first, if the requested URI end on `something.php` you rewrite to /something. Secondly, when a filename `.php` is requested and actually exists, the last part of the URI is taken and extended by `.php`. So the short version would be to only remove `.php` if the file doesn't exist. My rule does exactly that :/ RewriteCond is fulfilled if the requested file is non-existent and then it strips the `.php`.

Comment: Only the second part, adding `.php` if there is a file with the name `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` isn't handled, since it wasn't part of your original question, but if that should be done too, then you should stay with your last ruleset. edited my answer accordingly