# .htaccess redirects to remove php and redirect to https and non-www

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following in my `.htaccess` file to

- Remove www
- Redirect to https
- remove .php

This is my .htaccess:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to HTTPS & remove www                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301] 

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove .php extension                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

When I view the site in Firefox I get the following error:

> The page isn't redirecting properly. 
>   This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies

And Chrome warns about too many redirects

The URL is updated to what I would expect (www removed and https added). There are no other redirects in effect

Can anyone spot where I am going wrong?

Comment: I can't see anything that would cause a redirect loop. There must be something in conflict, like other rules ? Could you tell what url the redirect loop generates ? That'd help to debug it

Comment: Hi Justin - url generated is correct, and there are no other redirect rules. I have updated the question to include this information

Comment: Actually, what you see is *not* what you get, proof is the redirect loop. Could you look in the network console of Chrome to see what's wrong ? This way, we'll see what's the redirect loop and we could determine the source of the problem. High is the chance that you have a CMS (do you ?) that is configured to accept `http` or `www` (or both) only, which would explain the redirect loop.

Comment: What is your Apache version? Try replacing `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]` wiith`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_SCHEME} =http`

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242712/htaccess-remove-www-force-https-remove-php-and-remove-trailing-slash

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you will want the following in your .htaccess file:

```
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Redirect to HTTPS & remove www                                     |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
# | Remove .php extension                                              |
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)/?$ /$1.php [END]
```

This was borrowed from the accepted answer to the following similar topic:

[.htaccess - Remove www, force https, remove php and remove trailing slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43242712/htaccess-remove-www-force-https-remove-php-and-remove-trailing-slash)

Answer (score -1):

Try below code in your .htaccess file:

```
RewritEengine on
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [r=301,nc]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```